# iOS: Synching changes in iPad .ipa file using iTunes

Tags: ipad, synchronization, ipa, ios5.1, itunes-app

I have installed my enterprise iPad App using itunes successfully. When I have made some changes to app, replaced old App in iTunes Apps with updated one and synced it with iPad and noticed that it doesn't sync the latest version! The changes doesn't get reflected. I have to remove the old App from iPad and reinstall it again updated one. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Comment: Have you changed Info.plist's CFBundleVersion?

Comment: No! That might be an issue..let me check..Thanks!

Comment: If it's the same, it works via Xcode but not iTunes.

Comment: Hi @jrtc27 please put this as an answer. You were correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you change the `CFBundleVersion` for each new build to be installed through iTunes.

Comment: Does it matter what the bundle version is changed to? In other words, does it have to be a string which iTunes sees as "newer" or does it only matter that it's different?